# Kivy - missing 'self' argument on function binding

Tags: kivy, python-3.6, kivy-language

[Using Kivy 1.9.2-dev0]
Basically, I am working on a Network Drawing tool with Kivy. Right now I am trying to let the user add items to modelize the network.

First things first, I primarily want to add some Nodes to my drawing. To do that, I created a class ButtonPanel that will contain every button that will allow us to instanciate different kind of items.

Then, I created a different kind of popup for each item I will want to add. Here is the code for the "Add a node" GUI. Here, we can see NodePopup class. An instance of a NodePopup is created everytime I click on the button "Add Node". The function "checkbox_changed" of this class is where I get my problem from.

The class CustomPopup is a base class that will load the KV file, and all of my Custom Popups will inherit from it so I won't have to write it several times.

I also added a Decorator "toggle_form", which will be called everytime the state of the Checkbox has changed (thus, everytime we call the "checkbox_changed" function).

However, when I click on the checkbox, the program crashes and I get the following error:

> TypeError: checkbox_changed() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'self'

I don't really understand why do I get this error, as I am calling the function with the `root` keyword, which refers - as far as I know - to the root widget's instance, which is, in this case, an instance of the "NodePopup" class.

**Why am I getting this TypeError? How can I solve it?**

buttonpanel.py:

```
class ButtonPanel(GridLayout):
    btn_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    node_btn = ObjectProperty(None)
    build = BooleanProperty(False)

# This method will create a Popup containing a form, allowing us to put some info about the node we want to add.
def create_node(self):
    content = NodePopup(cancel=self.cancel)
    self._popup = Popup(title="Add a Node", content=content, size_hint=(0.2, 0.5))
    if self.build is False:
        self._popup.open()


class CustomPopup(BoxLayout):
    Builder.load_file(os.path.join(dirname(__file__), 'popups.kv'))


class NodePopup(CustomPopup):
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)
    slack_mode = BooleanProperty(False)
    form = ObjectProperty(None)
    slack_chkbox = ObjectProperty(None)

    # Function called everytime we click on a checkbox
    @toggle_form
    def checkbox_changed(self):
        if not self.slack_mode:
            print("POPUPS.PY\\CHECKBOX_CHANGED CALL\\", self.slack_mode)
            self.ids['form'].dismissed = False
        else:
            self.ids['form'].dismissed = True

# Decorator
def toggle_form(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.slack_chkbox.active:
            self.slack_mode = False
        else:
            self.slack_mode = True
        return func()
    return wrapper
```

popups.kv (relevant part) :

```
<NodePopup>:
    form: form
    slack_chkbox: slack_chkbox
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    orientation: "vertical"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint: [1, .1]
        Label:
            text: "Slack Node"
        CheckBox:
            id: slack_chkbox
            active: False
            on_release: root.checkbox_changed()
```

Here's an image of the (basic) NodePopup in question:

[image]

**P.S.:**
I already have another class using Popups which I use to load files. But when I load a network I use a static function, and I get no error, the network is loaded and everything seems to work fine. Does it mean I have to use only `@staticmethod` when I want to bind functions to Popup's children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I get it. The error was in the decorator... Just edited to

```
return self.func()
```

Which lead to another error, but I'll be able to figure it out by myself.